# Google spreadsheet copy values from one row to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 3 different sheets that you can see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UrJxWhhSESaFmdoLKRcK6UQnGNTMblHygrG8utZ6VVw/edit?usp=sharing).

What I would like to do is per each person in the 'person' sheet, create a row of the person in the 'stacs' sheets that will be repeated as many times based of the number of 'meals' that we have in the 'meals' sheet. So, per each person, I want to create personA + meal1 in row #1, personA + meal2 in row #2, personA + meal3 in row #3, etc.

I figured it out how to do this repeating the same code over and over again. The code works but it's very inefficient. I guess that there has to be a way of doing the same repetition that I'm doing in a much cleaner and simpler way. I'm just learning how to you use some scripting to improve my spreadsheet so any help with this will be very welcome!

Some Caveats:

- If you take a look at the spreadsheet, you will see that I'm using formulas in some cell to calculate the last row with value or the sizes of the ranges.
- In the 'meals' tab I have defined a name range with the meals. I'm not very proud of this, because the list of the meal will grow so I wonder if there is a more dynamic way of dealing with this instead of adjusting the range every time I add a new meal.

Here is the code that you also find in the spreadsheet:

```js
 function copyValuesA() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("names");
 var name = sheet.getRange("A2");
 var sheetMeals = ss.getSheetByName("meals");
 var rangeMeals = sheet.getRange("mealsNames");
 var sheetstacs = ss.getSheetByName("stacs");
 var lastRow = sheetstacs.getRange("B1").getValue();
 var mealCount = sheetstacs.getRange("D1").getValue();
 var lastRowMeals = sheetstacs.getRange("C1").getValue();
 var rangeOrigname01 = sheetstacs.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + mealCount);
 var rangeOrigname02 = sheetstacs.getRange("A1");

 name.copyTo(rangeOrigname01);

 var rangeDestMeals01 = sheetstacs.getRange("B" + lastRowMeals);

 rangeMeals.copyTo(rangeDestMeals01);

 }


function copyValuesB() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("names");
var name = sheet.getRange("A3");
var sheetMeals = ss.getSheetByName("meals");
var rangeMeals = sheet.getRange("mealsNames");
var sheetstacs = ss.getSheetByName("stacs");
var lastRow = sheetstacs.getRange("B1").getValue();
var mealCount = sheetstacs.getRange("D1").getValue();
var lastRowMeals = sheetstacs.getRange("C1").getValue();
var rangeOrigname01 = sheetstacs.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + mealCount);
var rangeOrigname02 = sheetstacs.getRange("A1");

name.copyTo(rangeOrigname01);

var rangeDestMeals01 = sheetstacs.getRange("B" + lastRowMeals);

rangeMeals.copyTo(rangeDestMeals01);   
}


function copyValuesC() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("names");
var name = sheet.getRange("A4");
var sheetMeals = ss.getSheetByName("meals");
var rangeMeals = sheet.getRange("mealsNames");
var sheetstacs = ss.getSheetByName("stacs");
var lastRow = sheetstacs.getRange("B1").getValue();
var mealCount = sheetstacs.getRange("D1").getValue();
var lastRowMeals = sheetstacs.getRange("C1").getValue();
var rangeOrigname01 = sheetstacs.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + mealCount);
var rangeOrigname02 = sheetstacs.getRange("A1");

name.copyTo(rangeOrigname01);

var rangeDestMeals01 = sheetstacs.getRange("B" + lastRowMeals);

rangeMeals.copyTo(rangeDestMeals01);   
 }


function copyValuesAll() {

copyValuesA();
copyValuesB();
copyValuesC();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your interested in a dynamic formula to accomplish this:

in your stacs sheet in column A cell 2 put:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(";",ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A&";",COUNTA(meals!$A$2:$A)))),";"))
```

and in cell B2:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(JOIN(";",meals!$A$2:$A$8),COUNTA(names!A2:A))),";"))
```

doing this will automatically account for new values

[image]

Comment: These formulas are AWESOME! They simply solve the problem very easily. Thanks a lot Aurielle!

Comment: Hi Aurielle, I'm not sure if you are going to read this since it's been some time. I have to say that your solution has been working amanzingly during all this time. The thing is that my Spreadsheet has become huge and this week I got this error in the formula: Error
Text result of REPT is longer than the limit of 32000 characters. Also, the Google Spreadsheet is now very heavy and it takes a lot of time to calculate. I'm thinking of migrating this spreadsheet into an Excel file and I'm wondenring if you know any formula that I can use to get this same result is Excel. Thanks in advance!